# Django get content associated to the tag when clicked

Tags: python, django, filter, tags

I wanted to know how I can filter the tags.

I mean : If this tag is clicked, show all the article who have this tag.
(django - 1.7.4 and python 2.7.9)

views.py

```
def tag(request):
    context = {}
    populateContext(request, context)
    return render_to_response('ajouter.html', context, Context({'tout_tags': Article.tags.all()}))

def innertag(request, id):
    context = {}
    populateContext(request, context)
    return render_to_response('innerajouter.html', context, Context({'tag': get_object_or_404(Article.tags, id=id)}))
```

ajouter.html

```
{% for tag in tout_tags %}

<a href="{% url "article.views.innertag" tag.id %}">{{ tag.name }}</a>

{% endfor %}
```

innerajouter.html

```
<h3>For the tag: {{ tag.name }}</h3>
//How can I filter ? To get only the selectioned tags ?
```

here is a view of my project:
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: could you show your models? That would be really helpful.

Comment: Also, is tag another one of your models, or is it some django package that I am not familiar with?

Comment: It looks like he's using [django-taggit](https://django-taggit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/custom_tagging.html)

Comment: There are a few more problems with your code that I see that I don't know will solve the problem. One, you should change tagID to just id in your view. Also your not importing any tag models. Also, usually the preferred way to attach a manager to a model is `objects = TaggableManager()` but, that is up to you. Finally, you are going to have to check the documentation for the django-taggit that you are using to figure out how to get tags from the database and filter other things using those tags through the manager you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanted to display all articles under a certain tag...

```
from django.template import RequestContext

def displayAllArticlesUnderTage(request, tagID):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    tag = tag.objects.get(id = tagID)
    #Note, I am not sure of your database relationship between the tags and 
    #the articles so you will probably have to change the next line...
    articles = Article.objects.filter(tag = tag)
    context_dict = { "articles" : articles, "tag" : tag }
    return render_to_response([your template name], context_dict, context)
```

I speculated on the relationship of your articles to your tag objects. If this was wrong please tell me.

---

my answer will depend on the way your articles are displayed. I'll just give the general syntax here...

```
{% for article in articles %}

    <h1>{{ article.titre }}</h1>
    <h5>{{ article.autuer }}</h5>
    <p>{{ article.contre }}</p>
    *Whatever other things you need from each article*
{% endfor &}
```

Comment: NameError at /article/tags/2

global name 'tags' is not defined How can I resolve this problem ? (I changed the code to adapt it)

Comment: def innertag(request, tagID):
 context = {}
 articles = Article.objects.filter(tag = tags)
 populateContext(request, context)
 return render_to_response('innerajouter.html', context, Context({"articles" : articles, "tag": get_object_or_404(Article.tags, id=tagID)}))

Comment: You have to insert the made of your tags model for it to work.

Comment: is there a difference If I use id=id and not id=tagID ?

Comment: No, the tagID I put in my function was just a parameter. I could be any name. id=id works the same as long as the parameter in your view is named id.

Comment: well I tried many possibilities with the code but I only get this error : NameError at /article/tags/2 : global name 'tags' is not defined

Comment: I just put the name tags in as a demonstration. The way you solve that problem is that you must find out what the real name of your tags model is. I don't know what it is.

Comment: did you import the tags model into your views?